# @media tags directly under style in HTML/PHP

Tags: html, css, media

I faced a strange problem while working on [snapchamp.com](http://www.snapchamp.com) responsive design. The @media tags were not working in custom css section of my theme which gets directly incorporated in html output (under head). That made me think that media tags are not effective under html/head section. However later I realized otherwise after posting here.

I was researching on what probably caused issue in first place and realized that inline css in head is getting priority lesser than linked css file (I was under impression that inline css had priority). Or Does position of link and inline style matter. Attached is a screen shot that show that linked css cj-entitlement is getting priority over inline css in index.

[image]

Please let me know what is true otherwise I will research more and post back.

Comment: They don't fail when I test that code: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAPDRsjeTJJAj4K0kTc57RWxwy40UbrU7Zs

Comment: Yeah realized now problem is only on live site why media not working. Are there any special consideration while putting media tags under head/style of html..

Comment: Order of rulesets matters of course (those that come later override what comes earlier regardless of the method you include it).